# Nuget - Is there a way to conditionally add files if the consumer is a web or desktop application (.NET)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget

I have a class library packaged as a nuget and consumed by both web application and desktop (winforms/wpf) applications.  Is there a way that I can conditionally add files (defined in my nuspec file) based on whether the consumer is a web or desktop application?

Update:
So within my nuget package I have a dependency on calling a web service. The credentials of this were actually hardcoded. I refactored to read in the credentials from a config file, but herein lies my issue. It can read in from either a web.config or app.config based on the consumers application type. From the project that is the nuget package I create transform files to add/remove appsettings that contain the username and password. So I create both app.config.transform and web.config.transform files. But I'm wondering if I can conditionally add one or the other based on the consumer?

[image]

Comment: Have you considered offering separate versions of your package? One intended for desktop, one intended for the web? And if they share some common components, create a 3rd package that both of them can depend on?

Comment: I don't know but I think that you are searching for dynamic linking like in C++. I don't know .Net correspondence to do that.

Comment: Yes, that was something I considered.  This is actually just a legacy thing that is referenced by a lot of other projects and we would just need to create a second project in source control and another namespace and build/release pipeline...So was just curious if this was technically impossible to do in one project.  But yes, we may have to go the separate versions of the package route.

Comment: Can you give an example of what your different offerings would contain?

Comment: Why would you transform the settings yourself? Let the user configure your modules with credentials in their app startup.

Comment: This is a legacy thing and used by lots of applications, let's say like 50 applications.  So for every consumer we will have to manually update the app.config and app.config.token file or web.config and web.config token file with the new keys and values.  What I'm proposing with the transform file, it will automatically update the config files with the appropriate keys and values.  All that will need to be done is to update the nuget version.